# Django & Nginx deeplinking domains (re-write rules or django urls?)

Tags: django, url-rewriting, webserver, nginx, deep-linking

I'm running Django behind Nginx (as FASTCGI) and I need to "*deeplink*" to a page in one domain from the root of another without redirecting or forwarding e.g.

Given that I have a domain general-stuff.com and a matching URL **http://general-stuff.com/books/** and that I have a second domain books-stuff.com I need a way to get the page served by **http://general-stuff.com/books/** at the URL **http://books-stuff.com/** how would I go about this?

**Edit:** Note that I also need the tree below these urls to work e.g. **http://books-stuff.com/book1/** should serve the page at **http://general-stuff.com/books/book1/** etc.

Thanks in advance
Richard.

Comment: Is anything served at the root of http://general-stuff.com (or elsewhere on this domain, I guess)? Is there a fixed set of "child" domains (e.g. http://books-stuff.com ) or does the solution need to account for an arbitrary number? It sounds like the redirect needs to happen at the Nginx level, not the Django level, but this tickles a lot of subtleties of the Nginx rewrite module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `proxy_pass` configuration in Ngxinx.

```
server {
   gzip on;
   listen       80;
   server_name  books-stuff.com ;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://general-stuff.com/books/;
      break;
   }
}
```

Should do exactly what you want